# How do I execute multiple shell commands with a single python subprocess call?

Tags: python, subprocess

Ideally it should be like a list of commands that I want to execute and execute all of them using a single subprocess call. I was able to do something similar by storing all the commands as a shell script and calling that script using subprocess, but I want a pure python solution.I will be executing the commands with shell=True and yes I understand the risks.

Comment: Can you provide a typical example of the type of commands you are looking to execute?

Comment: Can you use `&`/`;`/`&&` to chain the commands together? Why a single subprocess call though - why not loop that would give you more control over, for example, terminating early?

Comment: Use `;` to put them in sequence: `subprocess.call("do_A ; do_B ; do_C ; ", shell=True)`. Programmatically: `call(' ; '.join(commands), shell=True)`

Comment: any typical shell command will do, like ls maybe, I don't have a requirement to use one commands output as the next ones input, all the commands are independent.

Comment: An alternative: just start a shell and send the commands as input: `p = call("bash", stdin=PIPE); p.communicate("\n".join(commands))`.

Comment: Are they shell commands or external programs?

Comment: @Bakuriu when I try to start the shell with subprocess and then communicate the commands using pipe, the process hangs and doing a p.close() doesn't help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use semicolon to chain them if they're independent.

For example, (Python 3)

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.run('echo Hello ; echo World', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
>>> result
CompletedProcess(args='echo Hello ; echo World', returncode=0, stdout=b'Hello\nWorld\n')
```

But technically that's not a pure Python solution, because of `shell=True`. The arg processing is actually done by shell. (You may think of it as of executing `/bin/sh -c "$your_arguments"`)

If you want a somewhat more pure solution, you'll have to use `shell=False` and loop over your several commands. As far as I know, there is no way to start multiple subprocesses directly with subprocess module.

Comment: something must loop through the list of commands.  a shell can do this. python can do this.

Comment: @Skaperen exactly. It's just, if Python does the looping and `exec()` syscall, I'd consider it more pure, as OP wants.